# Getting multiple images when trying to apply a single one

Tags: image

I'm still fairly new to Blender - I have version 2.79. I am trying to apply a single image to part of a model. I have followed many steps and tutorials, but when it appears on the object it is multiplied into a tile pattern, which is not what I want. I'm still working out node usage; I don't know if I'm missing something. Also, I can't find the "options" panel in the M

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for reference? Are you using Cycles ore Blender Render material, and are you using only one UV layer or are you using a secondary UV layer for the placement of the decal?

Comment: Yes we lack information, perhaps try to select Clip instead of Repeat in the Image Texture node?